# Array of an object function

Tags: vb.net

I have a third party web service. With VB.Net, one of the parameters of the function I'm using accepts an array of `MyObject`. So if I wrote the code below, `SomeFunction` would work as expected.

```
    Dim myArr(0) As MyObject
    SomeFunction(myArr)
```

Since `myArr` could hold many elements I wanted to create a **different** function that would allow me to pass in the relevant element (0,1,2,3,4....) into `SomeFunction`, rather than passing in `0` (in this case manually).

I'm not sure how to do this. Could someone help here?

Comment: Please elaborate on "that would allow me to pass in the relevant element into SomeFucntion."  I am confused because you said SomeFunction takes an array, not a single element.

Comment: sure a little hard to explain but here goes. Using the above code works. In order for me to go through other elements i would have to write

    Dim myArr(1) As MyObject
    Dim myArr(2) As MyObject

So what i thought was to create another function that would process the array elements and pass the relevant one to the function.

The error i currently get if attempting my own way is 1-dimensional array of MyObjectt' cannot be converted to 'MyObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you're trying to pass in a single value of your object rather than an array, have you tried something like:

```
Dim myArr1 As MyObject
Dim myArr1 As MyObject

   SomeFunction({myArr1})
   SomeFunction({myArr2})
```

Or, more specifically, in your case:

```
Dim myArr(100) As MyObject

   ... code ...
   SomeFunction({myArr(20)})
```

... Something along those lines??

I apologize if I didn't understand your question correctly.